# Parsey mcparseface : how to get position of word in sentence along with parse tree

Tags: syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

I am using parsey mcparseface and syntaxnet to parse some text. I wish to extract the positional data of words along with the parse tree.

Currently what the output is:

```
echo 'Alice brought the pizza to Alice.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh

Input: Alice brought the pizza to Alice .
Parse:
brought VBD ROOT
 +-- ALice NNP nsubj
 +-- pizza NN dobj
 |   +-- the DT det
 +-- to IN prep
 |   +-- Alice NNP pobj
 +-- . . punct
```

how i need it to be

```
Input: Alice brought the pizza to Alice .
Parse:
brought VBD ROOT 2
 +-- Alice NNP nsubj 1
 +-- pizza NN dobj 4
 |   +-- the DT det 3
 +-- to IN prep 5
 |   +-- Alice NNP pobj 6
 +-- . . punct 7
```

or similar. (this will be particularly useful when there are many occurances of same word.)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit conll2tree.py
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/conll2tree.py

Changing `token_str` to

```
token_str = ['%s %d %s %s' % (token.word, tind,
           token.tag, token.label)
           for tind,token in enumerate(sentence.token,1)]
```

should do it.